# Invoking the compile lifecycle phase to test my source generating maven plugin

Tags: maven, testing, automated-tests, maven-plugin, generated-code

I am writing a maven plugin that generates source code. I have created my plugin project using the `maven-archetype-plugin` archetype.

The `maven-archetype-plugin` archetype creates a `project-to-test` under `src/test/resources`.

I would like to execute the `compile` lifecycle on this project as part of an automated test. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: The location `src/test/resources`  is simply wrong...generated code should be located in `target/generated-sources/XXX` ...

Comment: You may have misunderstood me. The `project-to-test` is created as part of `mvn archetype:generate`.

Comment: It's unclear what your question is.  The compile phase will automatically be run if you run `mvn test`